# PHP News Feed Share Button Disappears

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, publish, feed

I am using PHP to post status updates to some of my fan pages.

I am posting links, and all of the content loads properly, however, the share button disappears when the post is completed.

I have seen a few other people asking this same question and have had no answer.

If someone can help me find an answer I will make sure to tell the others.

Thank you everyone!

```
    public function addStatus($status)
    #   Used in:    FB Simple APi
    #           
    {

        if ($this->_user) {

            try {

                $dataArray = array(
                    'message' => $status,
                    'link'    => 'http://videomaniacsnetwork.com/wallposts/CZikEEIJiF.html'
                    );                  

                if ($this->_isPage && REPLY_AS_PAGE) {
                    $dataArray['access_token'] = $this->_getPageToken();
                }                   

                $publishStream = $this->_facebookObj->api('/' . $this->_userId . '/feed', 'post', $dataArray);

                if (TRACE) {$this->_trace[] = 'addStatus'; }
                return true;
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $this->_errorArray[] = 'Could not set status.';
                $this->_debugArray[] = $e;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no code shown so we wouldn't be able to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

May be the share button did not pass the "if" validation statemant if jou are using if statemant for posting the form. 
Add the php code validation for that form.